# Как сделать хитрый редирект в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Приветствую, господа.

Проблема: мигрировали с друпала на собственный движок и вскрыли целую серию косяков. Один из них не получается решить. На одной из страниц стоял модуль комментариев. Каждый комментарий получал свой уникальный url и, по сути, содержал дубль основной страницу. Итого, получилось накопить следующие дубли:

- `pagetitle%26post%3D-29647723_37`
- `pagetitle%26post%3D-34234235_37`
- `pagetitle%26post%3D-23425623_37`

Как одним махом все страницы с url оканчивающимся на этот `pagetitle%26`... редиректить (301) на единственный работающий сегодня url?

Comment: У вас ссылки вот прям так и идут, с %26, %3D?

Answer (score 1):

Можно как то так если URL (без кодированных символов) http://test.com/comp/index.php?pagetitle&post=-23425623_37 :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pagetitle [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Если есть кодированные символы пробуем играться с NE (не экранировать URI при выводе)